# Sql get top row in each continues group

Tags: sql

I met a sql question about getting the top row in each group. I searched existing answers, it's all about getting top one from different groups. In my situation, I have duplicated groups. For example,

[image]

this table is sorted by "place date", and what I want to get is each top row from groups as long as their "order Name" or "order volume" are different from previous row. so the output should looks like,

[image]

The row_number...partition by functions doesn't work here. I tried connected by function as well. But it seems not work either.

thanks in advance!

Comment: What RDBMS is this - oracle?

Comment: Yes, Oracle. Thanks for your reply Pinny. The answer is to use lag function, for your ref as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
OrderID     INT,
OrderName   VARCHAR(400),
OrderVolume INT,
PlacedDate  DATE,
Visit_Key   INT
)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(1,'A',24,'10/12/2012',432)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(2,'A',24,'10/13/2012',432)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(3,'A',24,'10/14/2012',432)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(4,'B',27,'10/18/2012',432)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(5,'B',27,'10/18/2012',432)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(6,'A',24,'11/25/2012',432)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(7,'A',24,'11/25/2012',432)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(8,'A',24,'11/25/2012',432)

CREATE TABLE #Test2
(
OrderID             INT,
OrderName           VARCHAR(400),
OrderVolume         INT,
PlacedDate          DATE,
Visit_Key           INT,
Prev_ordervol       INT
)
INSERT INTO #Test2
(
OrderID,            
OrderName,      
OrderVolume ,   
PlacedDate,     
Visit_Key,      
Prev_ordervol
)
SELECT
    MIN(OrderID) AS 'orderid',
    ordername,
    ordervolume,
    MIN(placeddate) AS 'placeddate',
    MIN(Visit_Key) AS 'visit_key',
    LAG(OrderVolume)  OVER (ORDER BY orderid) AS 'previous ordervol' 
FROM #Test
GROUP BY OrderVolume, ordername, orderid, placeddate



SELECT
    OrderID,
    OrderName,
    OrderVolume,
    PlacedDate,
    Visit_Key
FROM #Test2
WHERE OrderVolume != Prev_ordervol OR Prev_ordervol IS NULL

DROP TABLE #Test
DROP TABLE #Test2
```